# how to update multiple columns from a trigger MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

hi i am using mysql trigger to update a table on another table's insertion

this trigger works fine

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_pupil_subject` AFTER INSERT ON `pupil_marks`
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
   UPDATE  pupil_subjects  SET NumberOfStudens = NumberOfStudens + 1  WHERE NEW.SubjectID = SubjectID;
END$$
```

but this gives an error

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_pupil_subject` AFTER INSERT ON `pupil_marks`
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN
   UPDATE  pupil_subjects  SET NumberOfStudens = NumberOfStudens + 1 , AverageMarks = (SELECT AVG(Marks) FROM pupil_marks WHERE NEW.StudentID = StudentID ) WHERE NEW.SubjectID = SubjectID;
END$$
```

[image]

how to write this correctly , please help . thanks in advance .

Comment: Look at the query - it is missing `END$$` Do you have declaration of `$$` as delimiter before `CREATE TRIGGER`?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller hmm , i did that , but not it says #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: You need to drop trigger on the table for that specific event!

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya You have to drop previous trigger (`DROP TRIGGER update_pupil_subject`) before creating new one

Comment: ahhhh , guys , thanks a lot , i ll do this :)

Comment: hi i tried to remove that record form nformation_schema.triggers table , but it says that acces is denied ,and i can not delete that record :( , what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there were problems when sub-queries were used:

Can you try splitting the SQL statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `update_pupil_subject`
   AFTER INSERT
   ON `pupil_marks`
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE avg_marks   float;

   SELECT AVG(Marks)
     INTO avg_marks
     FROM pupil_marks
    WHERE NEW.SubjectID = SubjectID;

   UPDATE pupil_subjects
      SET NumberOfStudens = NumberOfStudens + 1, AverageMarks = avg_marks
    WHERE NEW.SubjectID = SubjectID;
END
$$
```

Edit: Use

```
SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE `table` = 'pupil_marks';
```

to get all triggers defined on `pupil_marks`. You can't have multiple triggers on an event as all actions can be covered in single trigger.

NOTE: I think `AVG(Marks)` is for a given subject, so modified trigger definition accordingly.

Comment: thanks , but giving the error ,#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table' my MySQL version is 5.5.8

Comment: hi i tried to remove that record form nformation_schema.triggers table , bu it says that acces  is denied ,and i can not delete that record :( , what should i do

Comment: use `DROP TRIGGER [IF EXISTS] [schema_name.]trigger_name` like `DROP TRIGGER  yourDBName.update_pupil_subject` If you were able to create trigger I presume you should be able to drop them too.

Answer (score 1):

declare a variable inside the trigger and assign it with the subquery

declare avg_mark integer default 0;
set avg_mark := (SELECT AVG(Marks) FROM pupil_marks WHERE NEW.StudentID = StudentID);

then use the variable "avg_mark" in your update statement...
it may work...

if not then check the delimiter just below phpmyadmin sql box . It should be "$$"